# Which is correct 'whose do you think is it?' or 'whose do you think it is?'

Tags: word-order

1. "Whose birthday do you think IS IT?"    or
2. "Whose birthday do you think IT IS?"

I know that for questions the verb to be goes in front of the personal pronoun, however, why I have this strong feeling 2 is the correct one? Maybe both?

Answer (score 6):

I think you are confused here by the fact that this sentence contains not just an interrogative main clause but also a subordinate "content" clause from which the complementizer *that* has been dropped. Only the main clause has subject/auxiliary inversion with *do-*support, not the subordinate clause.

*EXPLANATION*
Think about it from the point of view of the answer you expect. In its fullest form that would be something like this

```
 I  think [that] it is  X's  birthday.
```

Note that there are two clauses here: the main clause is *I think [Y], and Y, the something that you think, is the subordinate clause *[that] it is X's birthday*.

Now let's walk through the steps you perform to turn this answer into your question.

```
 (1)                 I     think [that] it is  X's  birthday.  
 (2)                You    think [that] it is whose birthday.
 (3) Whose birthday you    think [that] it is
 (4) Whose birthday you do think [that] it is
 (5) Whose birthday do you think [that] it is?
```

1. is the answer
2. Replace the *I* with *you*, and replace the word which you are asking about, *X's*, with the appropriate interrogative term, *whose*:
3. Move the interrogative term to the front; since it is not strictly a pronoun but a possessive modifying *birthday* it remains attached to the word it modifies and drags it along with it to the front.
4. Since this is a question, you must invert the subject of the main clause (*you*) with the auxiliary verb. But there's no auxiliary in the original, so you add *do* to play this role. This is called *do-*support.
5. Now you invert the auxiliary verb *do* with the subject; add a question mark and you're done.

The interrogative main clause now has the correct inversion, with *do* support. But the subordinate clause is not affected by this operation—it retains its original form, except that it has "lost" the element which you are asking about.

Comment: StoneyB you definitely are a perfect teacher. I always learn from your comprehensive answers. I feel happy that you are here to help:-))

Comment: Thank you very much Stoney B, your help is much appeciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not both. Number two is the correct form here.

> Whose birthday **is it**?

Is correct, but the question adds a second noun, and the verb we are asking about is **think**.

> Whose birthday do you **think** it is

You can simplify the question if this one is too confusing, for example

> What do you think it is?

This is also a more common, correct sentence, that displays the same behavior as the question you are asking about.